# CSS Animation: How can I put a text using pseudo-element for each image?

Tags: html, css

I currently have 4 images and I use the CSS animation to reveal a different picture every X seconds. The problem is that I'd like to put an unique text for each image. For example, for the first image, "First Image", for the second, "Second Image", etc.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <h1 id="all-available-styles">All available styles</h1>
        <div id="all-available-styles-block">
            <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="images/test2.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="images/test3.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="images/test4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#welcome-to
{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
    width: 75%;
}

#all-available-styles
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#all-available-styles:before, #all-available-styles:after
{
    content: "\f122";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}

#all-available-styles:before
{
    transform: rotate(250deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(250deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(250deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(250deg);
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#all-available-styles:after
{
    margin-left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(100deg) scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg) scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(100deg) scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: rotate(100deg) scaleX(-1);
}

#all-available-styles-block
{
    position: relative;
    height: 281px;
}

#all-available-styles-block img
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: allAvailableStylesBlockFadeInOut ease-in-out infinite 8s;
    -webkit-animation: allAvailableStylesBlockFadeInOut ease-in-out infinite 8s;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    width: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

@keyframes allAvailableStylesBlockFadeInOut
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    17%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    25%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    92%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes allAvailableStylesBlockFadeInOut
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    17%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    25%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    92%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes allAvailableStylesBlockFadeInOut
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    17%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    25%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    92%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes allAvailableStylesBlockFadeInOut
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    17%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    25%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    92%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#all-available-styles-block img:nth-of-type(1)
{
    animation-delay: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
}

#all-available-styles-block img:nth-of-type(2)
{
    animation-delay: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
    -o-animation-delay: 4s;
}

#all-available-styles-block img:nth-of-type(3)
{
    animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 2s;
}

#all-available-styles-block img:nth-of-type(4)
{
    animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
}
```

Result: http://screencast.com/t/WPcf8X2b7z

So for each image, a text in the middle. I think I can do it with a :before or :after, but I did find the solution.

Thanks to people who will try to help me.

Comment: Could you not wrap the image in a div and put a p tag in there for the text. Then target the div for the animation instead of the image?

Comment: If I do that, the text always appears: http://prntscr.com/61tr6j

Comment: You mean the text for each image is always displayed? Or the text for that particular image is always displayed?

Comment: I think I have a start by putting an ID for each image: http://prntscr.com/61tt9u

Comment: why not: <div id="targetMeForAnimation"> <p>Some Text</p> <img src="someImage"> </div>

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea, but I'll do it with CSS using: #all-available-styles-block #style-1:before
{
    content: "MY TEEESSTTTT";
}

Comment: I don't recommend you do that, but it will work for proof of concept I guess. Doing it that way reduces the semantics of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/qzrrqryd/

```
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <h1 id="all-available-styles">All available styles</h1>
        <div id="all-available-styles-block">
            <div class='image'>
                <img src="http://marcisischo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/TrollFace.png" alt="">
                <p> nice troll face 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class='image'>
                <img src="http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130116153004/uncyclopedia/images/c/cb/Internet-troll-face-explorer.png" alt="">
                <p> nice troll face 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class='image'>
                <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT6/MEb/dT6MEbgEc.gif" alt="">
                <p> nice troll face 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class='image'>
               <img src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/074/f/f/kirby_troll_face_by_arashi93_sama-d3bqrxs.jpg" alt="">
               <p> nice troll face 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Move images and text inside div, and add anima

Comment: Please dude, how can I show a link now for each text? Exemple for the text one, a link and for another text, a different link?

Comment: change <p> tag on <a> tag in each .image and add href option

Comment: I'd like to make this clickable and that each image has its own link: http://prntscr.com/6258d3

Comment: Than change div.image on a.image

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like each image has its own link: http://prntscr.com/625m6e